# DataTables - how to get the percentage of a column in html table

Tags: html, jquery, datatables

I am having a difficult time in calculating in getting the percentage for a column in my html table for datatables.

[image]

In the table above, I have figured out how to get the sum of each column, but for "Column D" totals, I need to get the percentage which will be "(total of column B / total of column C) * 100. Also column F will be (total of column E / total of column A) instead of the sum which is shows now.

The total for column D is blank because the javascript code that I used, could not sum up column D because I am using a percent sign. So with my current code, I want to sum for column A,B,C,E,G and the percent for column D, and column F would be column E divide by column A.

How can I go about to calculate these totals using Datatables and javascript? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // DataTable initialisation
    $('table.off-table1').DataTable({

            "searching": false,
            "info": false,
            "paging": false,
            "autoWidth": true,
            "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
                var api = this.api();
                nb_cols = api.columns().nodes().length;
                var j = 1;
                while(j < nb_cols){
                    var pageTotal = api
                .column( j, { page: 'current'} )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return Number(a) + Number(b);
                }, 0 );
          // Update footer
          $( api.column( j ).footer() ).html(pageTotal);
                    j++;
                }
            }
        
        });
});
```

```html
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.21/b-1.6.2/b-colvis-1.6.2/b-html5-1.6.2/b-print-1.6.2/cr-1.5.2/fc-3.3.1/kt-2.5.2/r-2.2.5/rg-1.1.2/rr-1.2.7/sp-1.1.1/sl-1.3.1/datatables.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.21/b-1.6.2/b-colvis-1.6.2/b-html5-1.6.2/b-print-1.6.2/cr-1.5.2/fc-3.3.1/kt-2.5.2/r-2.2.5/rg-1.1.2/rr-1.2.7/sp-1.1.1/sl-1.3.1/datatables.min.js"></script>


<style>

</style>

</head>



<table id="def-table1" class="def-table1" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">ID</th>
                                    <th scope="col">A</th>
                                    <th scope="col">B</th>
                                    <th scope="col">C</th>
                                    <th scope="col">D%</th>
                                    <th scope="col">E</th>
                                    <th scope="col">F</th>
                                    <th scope="col">G</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Totals</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                    <td class="minutes">41</td>
                                    <td class="minutes">14</td>
                                    <td class="minutes">33</td>
                                    <td class="minutes">42.4 %</td>
                                    <td class="minutes">42</td>
                                    <td class="minutes">1.02</td>
                                    <td class="minutes">8</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>2</td>
                                    <td class="minutes">8</td>
                                    <td class="minutes">2</td>
                                    <td class="minutes">6</td>
                                    <td class="minutes">33.3 %</td>
                                    <td class="minutes">5</td>
                                    <td class="minutes">0.63</td>
                                    <td class="minutes">1</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>3</td>
                                    <td class="minutes">29</td>
                                    <td class="minutes">11</td>
                                    <td class="minutes">25</td>
                                    <td class="minutes">44.0 %</td>
                                    <td class="minutes">33</td>
                                    <td class="minutes">1.14</td>
                                    <td class="minutes">5</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>4</td>
                                    <td class="minutes">7</td>
                                    <td class="minutes">1</td>
                                    <td class="minutes">5</td>
                                    <td class="minutes">20.0 %</td>
                                    <td class="minutes">5</td>
                                    <td class="minutes">0.71</td>
                                    <td class="minutes">1</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified this down by not using `this.api()` and only using the arguments passed to the callback and some basic array methods. Should be easier to work with now

```js
function tfootTotals(tfRow, data, start, end, display) {
    // display is array of data indices that are included in this view
    const pageData = data.filter((arr, i) => display.includes(i));
    // create array of column totals
    const totals = Array.from(pageData[0]).fill(0);
    pageData.forEach(arr => arr.forEach((e, i) => totals[i] += (+e) || 0));

    // calculate the special ones
    totals[4] = (100 * totals[2] / totals[3]).toFixed(1) + '%';
    totals[6] = totals[5] / totals[1];

    // set the tfoot cell text. slice ignores first one 
    // so indexing is one less than totals array
    $(tfRow.cells).slice(1).text(i => totals[i+1])
    // console.log(totals)
}
  
  
  // DataTable initialisation
  $('#def-table1').DataTable({
    "searching": false,
    "info": false,
    "paging": false,
    "autoWidth": true,
    "footerCallback": tfootTotals
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

  <table id="def-table1" class="def-table1" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">A</th>
      <th scope="col">B</th>
      <th scope="col">C</th>
      <th scope="col" class="col-d">D%</th>
      <th scope="col">E</th>
      <th scope="col" class="col-f">F</th>
      <th scope="col">G</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Totals</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>ff</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="minutes">41</td>
      <td class="minutes">14</td>
      <td class="minutes">33</td>
      <td class="minutes">42.4 %</td>
      <td class="minutes">42</td>
      <td class="minutes">1.02</td>
      <td class="minutes">8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td class="minutes">8</td>
      <td class="minutes">2</td>
      <td class="minutes">6</td>
      <td class="minutes">33.3 %</td>
      <td class="minutes">5</td>
      <td class="minutes">0.63</td>
      <td class="minutes">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="minutes">29</td>
      <td class="minutes">11</td>
      <td class="minutes">25</td>
      <td class="minutes">44.0 %</td>
      <td class="minutes">33</td>
      <td class="minutes">1.14</td>
      <td class="minutes">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td class="minutes">7</td>
      <td class="minutes">1</td>
      <td class="minutes">5</td>
      <td class="minutes">20.0 %</td>
      <td class="minutes">5</td>
      <td class="minutes">0.71</td>
      <td class="minutes">1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking to do, and so much cleaner. I greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Took me a while to get it down to this simple version after fiddling with the `api` which I haven't used for a few years. Once I got on this path it just made a whole lot more sense and no knowledge of the api methods needed